# SQL Server: using Lead to join next record that meets conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question with the usage of `lead()` function with certain conditions.

Let's say I have a table as follow:

```
    ----------------------------------
    id   |     time   |   condition  |
    1    |   12:00:00 |      fail    | 
    2    |   12:10:00 |      fail    |
    3    |   12:15:00 |     success  |
    4    |   12:20:00 |     success  |
```

I want to have a table containing a column that tells me when the next success time is, and exclude every failed records in between. So, like

```
    ---------------------------------------------------
    id   |     time   |   condition  |   next_success |
    1    |   12:00:00 |      fail    |     12:15:00   |
    3    |   12:15:00 |     success  |     12:20:00   |
    4    |   12:20:00 |     success  |       null     |
```

I know that I can probably play around with `lead()` function, but the closest I have seen is

```
select *, lead(time, 1) over (partition by condition order by time) as next_time from table
```

It is not quite what I want, because I don't just want to group them by failure or success, I want every record followed by the time of next **success**

Hopefully someone can give some ideas on how to solve this!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a CTE to filter the rows and a subquery to return the row of the next success:

```
with cte as (
  select *, lag(condition, 1) over (order by time) as prev_condition
  from tablename
)
select c.id, c.time, c.condition,
  (select min(time) from cte where time > c.time and condition = 'success') as next_success
from cte c
where coalesce(c.prev_condition, '') <> 'fail' or c.condition <> 'fail'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c59e3803c61f8561be23571b662bbaa8).
Results:

```
> id | time     | condition | next_success
> -: | :------- | :-------- | :-----------
>  1 | 12:00:00 | fail      | 12:15:00    
>  3 | 12:15:00 | success   | 12:20:00    
>  4 | 12:20:00 | success   | null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use only window functions for this purpose.

```
select id, time, condition, next_success_time
from (select id, time, condition,
             min(case when condition = 'success' then time end) over (order by time rows between 1 following and unbounded following) as next_success_time,
             lead(condition) over (order by time) as next_condition
      from t
     ) t
where not (next_condition = 'fail' and condition = 'fail')
```